# OpenGL Shader fails to compile

Tags: c++, opengl, shader

I'm currently trying to get into OpenGL. Unfortunately my shaders always fail to compile. The textfiles storing the shaders are successfully read into the string and passed to the glShaderSource - function. Since everything up to this point works i think my error is somewhere in the shader files themselves (vertex shader, fragment shader). I tried to output the error code, but i only get strange symbols.

```
    void GLSLProgram::compileShaders(const std::string& vertexShaderFilePath, const std::string& fragmentShaderFilepath)
{
    _programID = glCreateProgram();
    _vertexShaderID = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    _fragmentShaderID = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    if (_vertexShaderID == 0){
        fatalError("Vertex shader failed to be created !");
    }
    _fragmentShaderID = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    if (_fragmentShaderID == 0){
        fatalError("Fragment shader failed to be created !");
    }

    compileShader(vertexShaderFilePath, _vertexShaderID);
    compileShader(fragmentShaderFilepath, _fragmentShaderID);

    return;
}

void GLSLProgram::compileShader(const std::string& filePath, GLuint& id)
{
    std::ifstream vertexFile(filePath); 

    if (vertexFile.fail()){
        fatalError("Failed to open " + filePath);
        perror(filePath.c_str());
    }

    std::string fileContents = "";
    std::string line;

    while (std::getline(vertexFile, line)){
        fileContents.append(line + '\n');
    }

    vertexFile.close();
    const GLchar* contentsPtr = fileContents.c_str();
    glShaderSource(id, 1, &contentsPtr, nullptr); 

    glCompileShader(id);

    GLint success = 0;
    glGetShaderiv(id, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success); //returns success of most recent compilation
    if (success == GL_FALSE)
    {
        GLint maxLength = 0;
        glGetShaderiv(id, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &maxLength);

        // The maxLength includes the NULL character
        std::vector<char> errorLog(maxLength);
        glGetShaderInfoLog(id, maxLength, &maxLength, &errorLog[0]);

        // Provide the infolog in whatever manor you deem best.
        // Exit with failure.
        glDeleteShader(id); // Don't leak the shader.

        std::printf("%s\n", errorLog);
        fatalError("shader " + filePath + "failed to compile");

    }
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
#version 130

out vec3 color;

void main(){
    color = vec3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
}
```

Vertex Shader:

```
#version 130

in vec2 vertexPosition;

void main() {
    gl_Position.xy = vertexPosition;
    gl_Positionsition.z = 0.0;
    gl_Position.w = 1.0;
}
```

Comment: `while (std::getline(vertexFile, line))` \*sigh\* I'd love to know where everyone copy-and-pastes the same garbage code for reading files line-by-line instead of just reading the whole thing at once.

Comment: @apparatus_icarus: `GLint maxLength = 0;` you certainly won't get a usable error log from the GL if you are only providing a 0-szied buffer. There is not even room to add the string terminator, so that you just print some random data.

Comment: @derhass The line after declaring maxLength it is set to the length of the info log.

Comment: @Andreas: you're right, I missed that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your printf is broken. errorLog is passed as a vector< char > type which is not a valid type when you write "%s" in the format string.

Instead of:

```
std::printf("%s\n", errorLog);
```

...write:

```
std::printf("%s\n", &(errorLog[0]));
```